# How can I delete every resource created by an user in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an application with the following features:

- Users and autentication using `Devise` gem.
- Follower/following system using `act_as_follower` plugin.
- Posts that can be created by users.
- Each post can be liked (I have a join table for users and posts to create the `likes`).
- Each post can have an image, using `Paperclip` gem (I'll probably also use Amazon S3 in the future)
- Every user can have an avatar.
- Messaging system between users.
- Notifications for every kind of action.
- Users can comment on posts.

I want the user to have the option to delete his account. Devise already have this action but it isn't enough because it only deletes the `user` entry I think.

What I have to do is, delete all the posts that the user has created, delete the post's images. Delete every like, comment, message (sent/received), notification and follower/following relationship and finally the user account including the avatar image. In short, the action should delete every resource that have a `user_id` field related to the user to be deleted.

I'm also afraid doing this in a single request would take so much time and something wrong could happen, like half of the posts being deleted or something like this.

What's the best way to solve all this situation?

EDIT:

I used this and it worked fine.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

`acts_as_follower` automatically deletes every follower/following relationship and `Paperclip` also deletes every image related to the resource.

Comment: If my answer was correct, could you please accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all of your relations that are strictly dependent on having that user add

```
:dependent => :destroy
```

example

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

when the use is destroyed, so are his posts. You can also use destroy callbacks, but that is more complicated.